# How to remove schema from confluent schema registry with specific id?

Tags: confluent-schema-registry

I'm using the community version of confluent-schema-registry. As far as I understand, too many schema under same topics may cause compatibility issues later. I tried hard to delete useless schemas in the schema registry with the methods mentioned in the link below:
https://docs.confluent.io/4.0.0/schema-registry/docs/schema-deletion-guidelines.html

Afterwards the subject (topic) is empty (curl -X GET schema-registry:8081/subjects/, return []), but the schema is still there (curl -X GET schema-registry:8081/schemas/ids/25, return schema). I even tried removing the topic in the kafka-topics.sh. However, the schema seems to be still there and can be retrieved by id.

Has anyone run into the same problem? I'm curious if there is a way to remove the schema. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Schemas are softly deleted and you need to do another step for hard delete.
Check out the [latest documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#free-up-storage-space-in-the-registry-for-new-schemas)

> Simply deleting schemas will not free up space in the registry because
> this will always result in a soft delete and schema IDs are not
> reusable. The schema count tracks IDs, so the used number will
> increase as new schemas are added, regardless of whether you soft
> deleted schemas.
>
> Confluent Cloud now supports “hard delete” of a schema as a two-step
> process (soft delete, followed by hard delete) with the use of the
> query string, ?permanent=true on the second delete. If your Schema
> Registry reaches the maximum schemas limit, you can free up space for
> additional schemas by following the procedure described in Hard delete
> a schema in Schema Deletion Guidelines.